# How to pivot a column into a row?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel document where all the data is in one column and I would like it to be in one row instead.

So, `A1` remains at `A1`, `A2` to `B1`, `A3` to `C1`, `A4` to `D1` and so on until column A only has one populated cell.

Is there a tool or method to do this?

Comment: Search for "excel swap column to row" first answer => [Switch (transpose) columns and rows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-HP010224502.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function that you are referring to is called "transpose". You can transpose a row to make it into a column or a column into a row.

1. Copy the column (as in your case) you want to change to rows.
2. Right click on excel.
3. In the menu that appears look for "Transpose" under Paste options. If you are using older versions of excel, then, from the right click menu - select paste special. In the dialog that appears look for the check box next to "Transpose". Select and click OK

Comment: I'm sure that this is the right answer, but if you look at the OP's description of the desired result it would be a diagonal line not a row. :)

Comment: Agreed. I'm wondering if his requirement was to bring the data diagonally or not. Could it possibly be typo? Its always easy to say A3->B3 - where as in reality it is A3->C1.

Comment: Oh yeah it was sorry... it is supposed to be in one row.I tried the transpose thing but there aren't enough row slots to past it in, I currently have 21760 cells in A populated. The most that I can put in one row is only 16384.

Comment: I ended up spiting the document into two